# Tic tac toe vs computer class

Tags: c#, winforms, tic-tac-toe

I am writing a tic tac toe game. My logic is in a class that's why I have some difficulties. My board is a matrix. Firstly, I put X when I click a button, then the computer choose a block where to put O. In the class I save  the value of the matrix element but I don't know how to show it on the winform. Here is a part of my code..

```
public string ToggleNextLetter()
{
        if (!changedLetterX)
        {
            changedLetterX = true;
            return this.nextLetter = "X";
        }

        changedLetterX = false;
        MoveComputer();
        return this.nextLetter = "O";
}
```

//Reserve the position of the X from the form

```
public string[,] Matrix(int row, int col, string value)
{
        this.field[row, col] = value;

        return this.field;
    }

public string[,] MoveComputer()
    {

        //priority 1: get tick tac toe
        //priority 2: block x tic tac toe
        //priority 3: go for corner space
        //priority 4: pick open space

        string move;

        move = LookForWinOrBlock("O"); //look for win
        if(move == null)
        {
            move = LookForWinOrBlock("X"); //look for block
            if (move == null)
            {
                move = LookForCorner();
                if (move == null)
                {
                    move = LookForOpenSpace();
                }
            }
        }

        return move;
}

private void btn_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        int btnRow = Convert.ToInt32(btn.Tag) / 10;
        int btnCol = Convert.ToInt32(btn.Tag) % 10;
        btn.Text = game.ToggleNextLetter();
        game.Matrix(btnRow, btnCol, btn.Text);
        btn.Enabled = false;
        //btn.Text = game.ToggleNextLetter();

        if (game.HasWinner())
        {
            foreach (var control in Controls)
            {
                try
                {
                    Button b = (Button)control;
                    b.Enabled = false;
                }
                catch { }
            }
            MessageBox.Show("The winner is " + btn.Text);
        }
    }
```

Comment: My guess is your problem is how make "computer" press a button? Just separate the logic.. or you want suggestion on  how make the display?

Comment: I made the "computer" press a button but I can't display it on the board.

Comment: Please be more specific. Your code isnt complete, Your problem isnt clear. You already use a foreach(var control in Controls) You can search the button in the computer code and pass to MakePlay as parameter.

Comment: what return LookForOpenSpace? How you name your button controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just separate your functions

```
public string[,] MoveComputer() {
    // just add this line
    MakePlay(btnRow, btnCol, btnText);

    return move;
} 

private void btn_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    int btnRow = Convert.ToInt32(btn.Tag) / 10;
    int btnCol = Convert.ToInt32(btn.Tag) % 10;
    btn.Text = game.ToggleNextLetter();
    MakePlay((btnRow, btnCol, btn.Text);
}

private void MakePlay(int btnRow, int btnCol, string btnText) {
    game.Matrix(btnRow, btnCol, btn.Text);
    btn.Enabled = false;
    //btn.Text = game.ToggleNextLetter();

    if (game.HasWinner())
    {
        foreach (var control in Controls)
        {
            try
            {
                Button b = (Button)control;
                b.Enabled = false;
            }
            catch { }
        }
        MessageBox.Show("The winner is " + btn.Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: the method MakePlay will be in a seperate class, so I can't use btn.Text in it. Also, I can't pass the attributes because I won't know the move of the Computer, it has to put them by "itself"

Answer (score 0):

Try using a DataGridView

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //initiailze the datatable
            dt.Columns.Add("Col 1", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Col 2", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Col 3", typeof(string));

            //add three rows
            dt.Rows.Add();
            dt.Rows.Add();
            dt.Rows.Add();

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //examples of filling table
            dt.Rows[0][0] = "X";
            dt.Rows[0][1] = "O";
            dt.Rows[0][2] = "X";
            dt.Rows[1][0] = "O";
            dt.Rows[1][1] = "X";
            dt.Rows[1][2] = "O";
            dt.Rows[2][0] = "X";
            dt.Rows[2][1] = "O";
            dt.Rows[2][2] = "X";

        }
    }
}
​
```